# How to load XML file located inside the folder of the application in window phone 7?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml

I am developing window phone 7 application. I am new to the window phone 7 application. I have added XML file in my project by right clicking the project & selecting the Add -> New Item. I can then easily load the XML file in my application by using the following code

```
IsolatedStorageFile isfData = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            XDocument doc = null;
            IsolatedStorageFileStream isfStream = null;
            if (isfData.FileExists(strXMLFile))
            {
                isfStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(strXMLFile, FileMode.Open, isfData);
                doc = XDocument.Load(isfStream);
                isfStream.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                doc = XDocument.Load(strXMLFile);
                isfStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(strXMLFile, FileMode.CreateNew, isfData);
                doc.Save(isfStream);
                isfStream.Close();
            }
```

By using the above code I can perform the read & write operation in my XML file.

But the problem arises when I put my XML file into the folder. My problem is as follows:
I have added one folder named 'XML Files' in my project by right clicking the project name & selecting the Add -> New Folder in the visual studio. Then I have added a XML file into the 'XML Files' Folder by right clciking the folder & selecting the Add->New Item. When I put the XML file into the folder I am not able to Load it in my application. I have also tried with the following statement

```
isfStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("/XML Files/"+strXMLFile, FileMode.Open, isfData);
```

I am getting error at

```
doc = XDocument.Load(strXMLFile);
```

I am getting the error "Cannot find file '/XML Files/A.xml' in the application xap package." What should I do ? How to load the XML file loacted inside folder ? Is anything wrong in my code ? Can you please provide me any code or link through which I can resolve the above issue ?

Comment: Did you check that the "Build Action" is set to "Content" in the properties of your XML file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, make sure the `Build Action` for your XML file is set to `Content` and the `Copy to output` option is set to `Copy if newer` (or `Copy always`). Then, try this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load( "XML Files/MyXmlFile.xml" );
```

Note that there is no leading forward slash (/); I spent a few hours a few days ago stuck on this silly problem.

Comment: Tho i'm 4 years too late to comment, but it worked like a charm. Thanks.