# Reading an xml file with XDocument

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xamarin.android

I am trying to create an Android app with, which uses web services. I want to read a XML file using `XDocument`. I have created a folder in my project named `xmlfolder` and have placed my XML file named `myxml` into it.

I have tried other solutions on SO like [How to load XML file located inside the folder of the application in window phone 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538874/how-to-load-xml-file-located-inside-the-folder-of-the-application-in-window-phon) but does not seem to work. I keep getting the error:

`System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/xmlfolder/myxml.xml"`.

and

```
myxml.xml   myxml is null
```

Here is something I tried:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myFIileXML))
{
    XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load ("xmlfolder/myxml.xml");
    myFileXML = loadedData.ToString ();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [XDocument Reading XML file with Root element having namespaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19142606/xdocument-reading-xml-file-with-root-element-having-namespaces)

Comment: Are your files set as `content` and `copy always`?

Comment: @Monika thanks for replying. But I went through that link already, but doesnt seem to solve my problem. I just am not able to locate that file..

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Thanks for your attention. yes it is set to both the values

Answer (score 4):

I think you're not specifying the relative path correctly. You're also missing the . in myxmlxml, though I'm guessing that's just a typo in your post. Try this instead:

```
XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load ("../xmlfolder/myxml.xml");
```

Comment: yup my bad.. was a typo. You mean i need to specify the exact location of the myxml.xml on my machine?? eg: C:\Users\pc\Documents\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\xmlFiles\myxml

Comment: That would be specifying the absolute path, which would work too. You can also use the relative path, which I think you can do like above on Windows. Perhaps read up on the difference.

Comment: i tried doing what you suggested but still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't noticed yet, there is a nice `Resource` and `Assets` folder in your Android project, this is where Android requires all your app files to be. They cannot live outside unless they are a class. In this case you would probably want your file in the `Assets` folder, mark the file's Build Action as AndroidAsset. This way you can access your file like:

```
using (var sr = Assets.Open("myxml.txt"))
{
    var data = XDocument.Load(sr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I tried out your solution, now i get an Java.IO.FileNotFOundException even though I have placed the file in my Assets folder.

Comment: Did you set the build action to `AndroidAsset`?

Comment: Are you sure the filenames match? I wrote myxml.txt, but you are talking about myxml.xml. It is a trap!

Answer (score 0):

The Current Working Directory on Android is `/`, which isn't writable (and doesn't contains your applications files). Thus the error message:

> ```
> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/xmlfolder/myxml.xml".
> ```

The fix is to use a path that actually exists, e.g. `System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)`. Furthermore, note that you must have created this path "elsewhere", e.g. with `Directory.CreateDirectory()`.

If that's not the case, you may want to look into using **Build action** `EmbeddedResource` with `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream()`.